# Javascript replace string until a certain point

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a variable named `name` with the value `"myname yourname"`.

How can I replace everything with nothing (`""`) in that string until the **space** character?

So the new value of `name` would be be `"yourname"`.

Comment: is `var name = "myname yourname";` the string?, or only `myname yourname`

Comment: @NinaScholz `var name = "myname yourname";` is the string, and I need to somehow convert it to `name = "yourname";`

Comment: without `var ` in front?

Comment: @NinaScholz `var` is the Javascript syntax for declaring variables, it's not part of the value.

Comment: Can there be more than two words in the string? If there are, do you want to remove just the first word, or all but the last word?

Comment: @Barmar, i know `var`, at least i think, i know, but the question is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string using **[`split(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** then pop out the last element.

```js
var name = "myname yourname";

console.log(
  name.split(' ').pop()
)
```

---

Or using **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** or **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with regex

```js
var name = "myname yourname";

console.log(
  name.match(/\S+$/)[0]
);

// or

console.log(
  name.replace(/^[\s\S]+\s/, '')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a replace with a regex with `/.+ /` (search for at least any character followed by a space) and replace it with an empty string.

```js
console.log('myname yourname'.replace(/.+ /, ''));
```